# Print- Header & Footer missing in chrome + misaligned custom footer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, printing

Im working on a print style in chrome, an everything seemed fine, until i noticed that i didnt get any Footer or header on the print (the std. with page title, url etc., and i HAVE turned it ON in the print preview dialog).
So i just thought i would make one, so i just added a  with:

```
 .print-logo {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But that doesnt place itself all the way to the [right](http://i39.tinypic.com/30rqumr.jpg):

So i tried printing in IE10, and here both the default footer, and my custom shows up, and is placed correct.

Everything is setup with bootstrap, and print friendly version is made by using the `.hidden-print` class.

Its all in localhost ATM, but i have a saved html version of 1 page [here](http://thebekker.dk/work/ungdom/):

Anyone who have experience with these problems?

**UPDATE:**

Found that if i add

```
@page {
    size: A4 portrait;
}
```

that i will add my default footer and headers... but my custom one is still displaying wrong...

Comment: Not going through the hassle of downloading a .zip file and setting stuff up to test _your_ problem. Provide a (minimal) online example please, on jsfiddle.net or elsewhere.

Comment: sorry, here ya go 
http://thebekker.dk/work/ungdom/

Answer (score 0):

I got my best result printing in Chrome setting a fixed width (in px) to the page or main div. If not, Chrome try to fix the content changing font-sizes, etc.